# where is the qtcreator install builder xml file

Tags: qt

To package the qtcreator installbuilder has been used. Where is the xml file that is used for packaging the qtcreator.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for QtCreator is available at http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator - but it doesn't appear to contain anything related to the setup packages. My guess is that the setup package scripts are not open source.